# How to change scatter point size on Seaborn's relplot (seaborn.relplot not regplot)? Seaborn 0.9.0

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

**I would like to change the size of the scatter points.**

None of these work:

> `sns.relplot(x='columnx', y='columny', hue='cluster', data=df)`
>
> `sns.relplot(x='columnx', y='columny', hue='cluster',
>   scatter_kws={'s':.01}, data=df)`
>
> `sns.relplot(x='columnx', y='columny', hue='cluster', kwargs={'s':.01},
>   data=df)`

Comment: you can pass an argument `size` with any variable.

Comment: I believe `size` refers to how big the points are relative to some other variable. I was inquiring on how to reduce the size of ALL the points (not dependent on any other variable).

Answer (score 14):

Since the underlying function is `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=None)`, filling in the s=None to a suitable integer changes the size of ALL the points.

```
sns.relplot(x='columnx', y='columny', hue='cluster', data=df, s=10)
```